# flutter don't use plugin versions that require android 31

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have an essential plugin that hasn't been updated in a year. I made the mistake of updating flutter, and now, when I try to build, it is telling me about a whole list of plugins that require android 31. Unfortunately, android 31 breaks the one plugin that I *must* use. Caret notation in the pubspec.yaml is funny because the documentation says it's supposed to choose a version of the package that works with the dependencies, but it's just not doing that.

Comment: It's no solution, but I ended up just having to stop using that plugin. Too many other flutter plugins required newer versions of software.

Answer (score 1):

Run `flutter downgrade` in command line or reinstall your old version.